# Solve for bound of $\sigma(n)$ from harmonic series.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, number-theory, harmonic-analysis

I am given the harmonic series, $H_n$. How can I show that for $n\geq 1$, $$\sigma(n)\leq H_n+e^{H_n}\ln{H_n}$$

By the way, if you're not familiar with it, $\sigma(n)$ is the sum of all positive divisors of $n$.

I have no idea where to start.

Comment: Hmm! nice try :)!

Answer (score 1):

In case this was a question in good faith:

since this problem is equivalent to the Riemann Hypothesis,  don't expect to actually prove it.

[LAGARIAS](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0008177v2.pdf)

For the curious, the best of the elementary RH versions to experiment with is the first one, by Jean-Louis Nicolas (1983). It says that RH is equivalent to the conjecture that, for all [primorial numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial) $P,$
$$ \frac{P}{\varphi(P)} > e^\gamma \log \log P $$
The point is that it is not difficult to get a computer to compute both sides of this for very large $P.$ The criterion of Lagarias and that of Robin (student of Nicolas) depend on working with colossally abundant numbers, which take real work.